# add notes in Data table flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

I have a flutter app, and I have a Datatable into it,

I  make the user choose some product and put those products into that data table,,

that works fine!

but if the user adds some note to one product, can I put this note in one line under the product and complete the table?

the base table is here :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hUcS.jpg

this is my code :

```
 Widget DATATABLE() {
return DataTable(
  columns: [
    DataColumn(label: FittedBox(child: Text(arabic('Product')))),
    DataColumn(label: FittedBox(child: Text(arabic('Price')))),
    DataColumn(label: FittedBox(child: Text(arabic('Quantity')))),
    DataColumn(label: FittedBox(child: Text(arabic('Total')))),
  ],
  rows: [
    DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell( FittedBox(child: Text('{element.name}'))), //product name
      DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.unitPrice}'))), // product price
      DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.quantity}'))), // product quantity
      DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.unitPrice * element.quantity}'))),
    ]) ,
    DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell( FittedBox(child: Text('{element.name}'))), //product name
      DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.unitPrice}'))), // product price
      DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.quantity}'))), // product quantity
      DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.unitPrice * element.quantity}'))),
    ]) ,
    DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell( FittedBox(child: Text('{element.name}'))), //product name
      DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.unitPrice}'))), // product price
      DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.quantity}'))), // product quantity
      DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.unitPrice * element.quantity}'))),
    ]) 
  ],
  sortColumnIndex: 0,
  sortAscending: true,
);
```

}

how can I add the note under the product, like that :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGyWh.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget DATATABLE() {

  return DataTable(
    columns: [
      DataColumn(label: FittedBox(child: Text(arabic('Product')))),
      DataColumn(label: FittedBox(child: Text(arabic('Price')))),
      DataColumn(label: FittedBox(child: Text(arabic('Quantity')))),
      DataColumn(label: FittedBox(child: Text(arabic('Total')))),
    ],
    rows: [
      DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell( Column (
          children: [
            FittedBox(child: Text('{element.name}')),
            FittedBox(child: Text('Note --------------------------------------')),
          ],
        )), //product name
        DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.unitPrice}'))), // product price
        DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.quantity}'))), // product quantity
        DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.unitPrice * element.quantity}'))),

      ] ) ,

      DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell( FittedBox(child: Text('{element.name}'))), //product name
        DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.unitPrice}'))), // product price
        DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.quantity}'))), // product quantity
        DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.unitPrice * element.quantity}'))),
      ]) ,
      DataRow(cells: [
        DataCell( FittedBox(child: Text('{element.name}'))), //product name
        DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.unitPrice}'))), // product price
        DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.quantity}'))), // product quantity
        DataCell(FittedBox(child: Text('{element.unitPrice * element.quantity}'))),
      ])
    ],
    sortColumnIndex: 0,
    sortAscending: true,
  );}
```

Make the necessary alignments to the text.

Comment: this does not work, because the "'Note --------------------------------------'" put in the first cell in the row, I need to marge al the row in one cell and put the note into it,

Comment: If you want it that way its better to go with Table Widget rather than DataTable Widget. You have can change the cells the way you want there..